# Show selected date on CalendarView in a Listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, calendarview

i'm new to android and i need help to complete an exercise.

I need to show selected date data on CalendarView in a Listview, retriving the data from a sqlite database.

Like i click on 25/5 on CalendarView and it show the data for this date below it in a ListView.

Already tried to search for an answer but i couldn't find anything related, also i'm not a native english speaker so if the question is too vague, please tell me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see [ask]. No one will do your homework, especially based on mushy requirements. This is a site for specific questions related to coding, and you are asking for help on an entire solution. Your best bet is to describe what you want to do, what you have tried (including a [mcve]), and what results you get. You are expected to do your own research and show your work, especially for homework questions.

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to do my homework, i'm simply asking how i could do it, because i could not find a suitable example and don't know how to start.

Comment: How to you get a CalendarView? How do you get the results from it? How to you update another View with those results? What have you _tried_?